# Symfony 4.3 Submit form with Ajax and wrote data in database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, symfony

I'm pretty new to Ajax and i'm trying to submit a register form with Ajax and Symfony but i'm pretty stuck on the steps to do it:

In my Controller:

```
    /**
     * @Route("/inscription", name="security_register")
     */
    public function register(Request $req, ObjectManager $manager, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $encoder)
    {
        $user = new UserSecurity();
        $form = $this->createForm(UserRegisterType::class,$user);

        $form->handleRequest($req);

        if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $hash = $encoder->encodePassword($user,$user->getPassword());

            $user->setPassword($hash);
            $manager->persist($user);
            $manager->flush();
        }

        return $this->render('security/register.html.twig', [
            'title' => 'Doggn - S\'inscrire',
            'form' => $form->createView()

        ]);
    }
```

in my app.js

```
//Display the register form on the index page
const getRegisterForm = (e) =>{
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    url: '/inscription',
    method: 'GET',
    dataType: 'html'
  })
    .done((res)=>{
      $('html').html(res)
      $('.registerSubmit').on('click',handleSubmitForm)
    })
    .fail(()=>{
      console.log('error')
    })
}

//Submit the form with Ajax
const handleSubmitForm = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  let email = $('#user_register_email').val()
  let password = $('#user_register_password').val()
  let confirm_password = $('#user_register_confirm_password').val()
  let username = $('#user_register_username').val()

  console.log(email)
  console.log(password)
  console.log(confirm_password)
  console.log(username)

  $.ajax({
    url: '/inscription',
    method: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
      'user_register[email]':email,
      'user_register[password]':password,
      'user_register_confirm_password':confirm_password,
      'user_register[username]':username,
    }
  })
    .done((res)=>{
      console.log(res)
    })
    .fail(()=>{
      console.log('ERROR ON SUBMIT')
    })
}

$('#btn-connect').on('click',getRegisterForm)
```

with my console.log i see i got the 4 values of my form, but i don't really know how to send them to my controllers.
My Ajax request in handleSubmitForm don't send the data and return me the fail method.

Answer (score 0):

You have to serialize your form like this

```
$.ajax({
    url:'/inscription', // if you can use $('#YOUR_FORM').attr('action')
    method: 'POST',
    data: $('#YOUR_FORM').serialize()
    ....
});
```